# How can I issue a SQL Statement against my database and have it create a collection?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using EF6 but I don't know if there is any difference between that and earlier versions.

I have the following context:

```
public IdentityContext()
        : base("name=Identity")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<IdentityContext>(null);
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        Database.Log = logInfo => Debug.WriteLine(logInfo);
    }

    public DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
```

What I would like to do is to issue a SQL query against this:

I saw one example (not related to my context) which is:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); 
}
```

But this does not make any sense to me as I cannot see why there is .Blogs after the context.

For my context above can someone explain how I can issue a simple sql statement to get the Id from the AspNetUser table and place these in a collection.

Note that I am using EF6 but in this case I am not sure that is relevant to the question if I query the context. My real needs are for a complex SQL but first I need some suggestion to get me started. Thanks.

Comment: why are you using `BloggingContext` when your context is `IdentityContext`?

Comment: Hmm that's the example I copied from. I am confused when I see that example so I posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .SqlQuery, you're kind of bypassing the beauty of using LINQ-style lambda expressions to query your database.

You might need to fiddle with the syntax a bit, but something like this should work for your initial requirement of getting user IDs:

```
var allMyIds = context.AspNetUserLogins.Select(l => l.Id).ToList();
```

or, if you prefer...

```
var allMyIds = (from l in context.AspNetUserLogins
                select l.Id).ToList();
```

However, if you really need to execute SQL directly, you can do it on one of the DBSet classes as in your question (in which case the EF makes a valiant attempt at change tracking), or if it's a general query you just want to execute that returns primitive types and isn't specific to any one table, do it against the `Database` class using `ExecuteSqlCommand`:

```
var allMyIds = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select id from AspNetUserLogins");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: My SQL is more than 10 lines of joins and where clauses. I was wanting to do a direct query of the database as all I need is one field. Sorry maybe I should have been more clear. It was just an example. It's important for me to be able to enter the SQL directly.

Comment: Multiple joins and where clauses not a problem using LINQ! You can even build it up in stages in your code. Nothing will execute on the db until you evaluate it to try and get the results, e.g. with the ToList() call in my examples above, then it'll prepare a single db call matching the conditions you specified.

Comment: I guess though, if you just want to execute SQL statements directly, is there any value in using the Entity Framework, you could just use SqlClient classes or their equivalent, depending on the db engine you're targetting?

Comment: Well I know what you are saying but I have many to many tables in the join and I am getting old so I would like to do the most simple way :-)  I will leave the fancy stuff to younger guys and girls.

Comment: Okay! Check my updated answer below, includes the "generic" way to execute SQL against a context.